# lux-api package installation python

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am trying to install lux-api package to do EDA. I am getting the below error

[image]

[image]

I tried upgrading pip and setuptools as was suggested elsewhere but still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the package did not require fcntl, but setup.py was invoking py2app, which does.  I could tell because the error originated from py2app\util.py.  I actually fixed it by uninstalling py2app and then retrying the pip install.

```
pip uninstall py2app
pip install lux-api
```

Comment: Nice catch. I had a spurious old reference to `py2app` in my `requirements.txt` which was causing this situation on windows. Once I removed `py2app` from my `requirements.txt` pip stopped trying to install `fctnl`, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fcntl is a Linux model, so if you run the project on Windows, it raises an ImportError or ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named 'fcntl' because fcntl is not available on Windows.

There is a workaround you can do to bypass this error, if you don't need to use the fctnl functions. For this you have to go to where your python packages are installed, something like `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages`

And there you create a folder named "fcntl". In this folder you create a file called "fcntl.py" with the following code inside:

```
def fcntl(fd, op, arg=0):
    return 0
        
def ioctl(fd, op, arg=0, mutable_flag=True):
    if mutable_flag:
        return 0
    else:
        return ""
    
def flock(fd, op):
    pass
        
def lockf(fd, operation, length=0, start=0, whence=0):
    pass
```

Now you should be able to install the lux-api package on your Windows.